# sqlcipher cannot query data through conditions

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite

I have a sqlcipher encrypted database (ver 4.5.1). This database can use "select * from xxtable;" to query all contents.There are 80 pieces of data。

Field 10001 in this table is an integer type. And the field name is also a number. It is used to record the timestamp.

Using "select * from xxxtable where [10001] >= 1693447225" will return the current 1693447225 timestamp data.

Using "select * from xxxtable where [10001] == 1693447225" will return the current 1693447225 timestamp data.

I can't use "SELECT * FROM xxxtable WHERE [10001] between 1693447225 and 1693453232" wit doesn't return any data.

I can guarantee that there are 4 pieces of data information in the above timestamp.

It should be normal to use "select * from xxxtable" in the database, but I don't understand why I can't query any data through the where >= condition.

---

The return values of sqlite3_exec(sql) for the above operations are all 0, without any errors or exceptions.

---

But I back up the database once through sqlite3_backup_init, then I can query the data content I want through the above sqlite statement.

But when used in the environment, it cannot receive every query and sqlite3_backup_init is executed.

```
sqlite3* db = nullptr;
    int iret = sqlite3_open(dbpath, &db);
    if (iret != 0)
    {
        return iret;
    }

    iret = sqlite3_key(db, g_key, 16);
    if (iret != 0)
    {
        return iret;
    }
      
    char* perr = nullptr;
    iret = sqlite3_exec(db, ssql, callback, NULL, &perr);
    if (iret != 0)
    {
        printf("%s \n", perr);
        free(perr);
        return iret;
    }

    sqlite3_close(db); 
    return iret;
```

Comment: I didn't understand what is the question here. Can you highlight the issue you face with the posted code the inputs you give and your expected output?

Comment: @kiner_shah Thank you for your attention. This problem is a problem with sqlcipher. I solved it with the latest version.